# using getopts to have 1 option require 4 options

Tags: bash, shell, getopts

I have been trying to read a lot about getops for bash because I have a project that requires the use of it for a script. The issue is I cannot find what I want to call nested options (if its even called that) For the project I am required to have say 3 options that are optional. But if the user choses say option `-i` they are required to have options `-f -l -e -n` how would I be able to implement that?

Comment: You would process each of the five arguments and set a variable for each. Then you'd check if `i` was used but `f` etc wasn't, in a regular `if` statement, and exit with a message if they weren't

Comment: okay I am getting that @"thato". but what would the command to be to pull an argument from a specific option. So if I store the value of each of the `-flen` parameters. what could I use to verify that `-f` was actually used. I am new to this whole bash environment and have never used getopts before. 

`while getopts ":if:l:e:n:" opt; do
     case $opt in
             i) if [ *command needed to verify -f was used* && *etc with -len* ]
                then
                     insert_contact
                fi;;
             l) lname= "$OPTARGT";;
     esac
done`

Comment: Each of the cases should only set a variable, e.g. `case $opt in i) i_was_specified=1;; f) f_was_specified=1; ...;; esac`. Only after your while loop is done parsing all options should you try to do any actions based on them. At this point, you can easily check `if (( i_was_specified )); then if (( !f_was_specified || ! n_was_specified )); then echo "Fail"; exit 1; fi; ...`

Comment: I think i got it, if you could just verify it. So for `-i` I would basically be setting a flag. for say `-f` I would set a variable from f that was entered. Then I should be able to pass that to my functions and test the data properly.

Comment: Pretty much, yes